# How to retrieve the Max Row per group when the partition is a DateTime column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

From MS SQL 2014, I'm trying to get the maximum value of "In_Max" when the partition is a DateTime column.

In my example, I want to retrieve this line:

```
2017-12-17T02: 08: 46.4 | 19977300
```

SQL:

```
 SELECT DateTime,
        sum(In_Max) OVER (PARTITION BY CAST(DateTime as date)
                          ORDER BY DateTime ASC
                          ROWS BETWEEN 3 PRECEDING AND 3 FOLLOWING
                         ) AS sum1
 FROM  yourtable
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/91f0d/5

Do I have to extract date and time from DateTime and then apply a rank?

Comment: You get a maximum value with `MAX`, not with `SUM`.

Comment: The goal is to know the busy hour, this is the reason why I used sum and not max in the sliding window. The In_max column name may create some confusion.

Comment: No, it's not the name. You say above that you want "the maximum value of In_Max", but in your code you have `SUM(In_max)` which is not the maximum but the sum as the function's name suggests.

Answer (score 0):

If you want just one row, you can use `TOP (1)` and `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT top (1) DateTime,
       sum(cast(In_Max as int)) OVER (PARTITION BY CAST(DateTime as date) ORDER BY DateTime ASC ROWS BETWEEN 3 PRECEDING AND 3 FOLLOWING) AS sum1
FROM  yourtable
ORDER BY sum1 DESC;
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/91f0d/6) is the SQL Fiddle.

Comment: yes, thank you but we must consider a month of data and for each day of the month find the maximum "sum1" of the day.

Comment: @Lolo- . . . Your question is quite clear that you want one row:  "In my example, I want to retrieve this line".  You should ask another question if you have a different question.  Provide sample data, desired results, and a good explanation.  Modifying this question is rude, because you will invalidate answers.

Answer (score 0):

From your comment to Gordon's answer I gather you want to get the maximum `in_max` per day for a given month. That's mere aggregation:

```
select
  cast(datetime as date) as day,
  max(in_max) -- or sum if you want the sum and not the maximum
from yourtable
where year(datetime) = 2017 and month(datetime) = 12
group by cast(datetime as date);
```

Comment: select
  cast(datetime as date) as day,
 --max(in_max) -- or sum if you want the sum and not the maximum
 sum(In_Maxbps) OVER (PARTITION BY cast(datetime as date) ORDER BY cast(datetime as date) ASC ROWS BETWEEN 3 PRECEDING AND 3 FOLLOWING) AS  Maxbps --> see the error below
 --max(In_Maxbps) as Maxbps --> no problem 
from InterfaceTraffic
where year(datetime) = 2017 and month(datetime) = 12
group by cast(datetime as date);

Comment: the error is: Column 'InterfaceTraffic.In_Maxbps' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: I don't understand why you want to apply `SUM OVER`. What is wrong with the simple `MAX` or `SUM`? What do you need a windowing function for? What is 3 preceding and following for? Anyway, in my query result there is no `In_Maxbps`, so you cannot apply `SUM OVER` to it.